# Javascript: access an object property whose name starts with a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, hashmap

I'm creating a **Javascript** / **jQuery** application.

I need to process a **JSON** response that represents a `HashMap`, like this:

```
  {
    "accounts": {
      "MediaFire": {
       "provider": "MediaFire",
       "usedStorage": "779680",
       "totalStorage": "53687091200"
      },
      "4Sync": {
       "provider": "4Sync",
       "usedStorage": "620692",
       "totalStorage": "16106127360"
      }
    }
  }
```

I use a pasing function (which I can't control), which returns the parsed JSON response in an object `result`.

When I try to access the `4Sync` like this:

```
var usedStorage = result.accounts.4Sync.usedStorage; //doesn't work
```

it doesn't work, I think **it's because of the *4* at the beginning**... The same operation with the other object works fine:

```
var usedStorage = result.accounts.MediaFire.usedStorage; //works
```

I know the `result` object contains the object `4Sync`, but I can't access it. Here is a screenshot of Chrome's console:

[image: screenshot of Chrome's console]

Is there any workaround to solve this?

Comment: Note that this issue has nothing to do with JSON: JSON is the string representation _before_ you parse it. Your `result` variable references an object that is the result of parsing the JSON. The issue is "how to access an object property that starts with a digit"...

Comment: @nnnnnn That's definitely true, I've edited the title...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use square brackets:

```
var usedStorage = result.accounts["4Sync"].usedStorage;
```

Property identifers can begin with a number, but member expressions with the `.` character will only allow valid variable identifiers (since anything else is ambiguous). To get around this, you can use the square bracket syntax, which is equivalent but allows the use of any string.

If you're interested, here is [the grammar](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2):

> *MemberExpression* :
>       *PrimaryExpression*
>       *FunctionExpression*
>       *MemberExpression* `[` *Expression* `]`
>       *MemberExpression* `.` *IdentifierName*

Notice how square brackets can contain any expression, but the `.` can only be followed by an [IdentifierName](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6) (basically, any valid identifier, plus reserved words in ES5).