# JavaScript Issue using JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm pulling a JSON object via Meteor, and I'm retrieving it correctly

https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD

```
{
  "24h_avg": 147.77,
  "ask": 144.85,
  "bid": 144.33,
  "last": 144.81,
  "timestamp": "Thu, 17 Oct 2013 02:30:18 -0000",
  "total_vol": 79387.48
}
```

When I try to use the values, I get the following results

```
obj.ask
144.96
obj.24h_avg
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
obj.total_vol
79773.46
```

Why am I getting an issue with the 24h_avg? I'm pretty darn lost here!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: Even though you are getting the data as JSON, the problem itself has nothing to do with JSON. The problem is related to JavaScript syntax rules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: access an object property whose name starts with a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083883/javascript-access-an-object-property-whose-name-starts-with-a-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[]` notation on the object to access the values with the key having invalid characters for a key (Here they start with digits, same applies to other chars like `-` etc in the key).

So try

```
 obj["24h_avg"]


 obj.24h_avg // You are accessing a property it needs to be a valid identifier.

 obj["24h_avg"] // You are accessing a property value using ["property_name"] it need not  be a valid identifier.
```

Comment: Wow great! I thought that the square brackets were only to access array values and you have to use the "." for object values.

Comment: @VarunJain No, You can access object keys with the bracket notation, In fact Array is an object as well.

Comment: @VarunJain: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Answer (score 1):

keys cannot start with digits, so need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to access the member

so use

```
obj['24h_avg']
```