# How to access API variable that starts with a number?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have accessed others parameters from an API using e.g:

```
dayTemp={`${Math.floor(weather?.main?.temp_max - 273)}°C`}
```

However when I'm trying to access rain:

```
rain={`${weather?.rain?.1h}`}
```

I get an error:

> An identifier or keyword cannot immediately follow a numeric literal.

How can I access weather.rain.1h?

Comment: Does `weather?.rain?["1h"]` work? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Identifier_after_number

Comment: Yeah square brackets property access notation is the way to go. You can even put variables in there like `weather.rain[\`${Math.random()}\`]`

Comment: This worked: weather?.rain?.["1h"]. Thanks @lux.

Comment: Please look at tags before you use them. `API` tag explicitly says "DO NOT USE". Also, this has nothing to do with APIs and everything to do with JavaScript objects, property names, an how to access them

Comment: Duplicate: [Javascript: access an object property whose name starts with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083883/javascript-access-an-object-property-whose-name-starts-with-a-number)